# Adding extension in CSR for generating an intermediate certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509, tls1.2, csr

I am generating a Certificate Signing Request for an intermediate certificate. I want to make the certificate a certificate authority (CA), so I want to add the basic constraints extension in CSR. I am currently using the following code

```
exts = sk_X509_EXTENSION_new_null();
add_ext(exts, x509_req, NID_basic_constraints, "critical,CA:TRUE");
X509_REQ_add_extensions(x509_req, exts);
sk_X509_EXTENSION_pop_free(exts, X509_EXTENSION_free);
```

The add extension function looks like this

```
int add_ext(STACK_OF(X509_EXTENSION) *sk, X509_REQ* req, int nid, char *value)
{
X509_EXTENSION *ex;
X509V3_CTX ctx;
X509V3_set_ctx_nodb(&ctx);
X509V3_set_ctx(&ctx, NULL, NULL, req, NULL, 0);

ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, &ctx, nid, value);
if (!ex)
{
    log("X509V3_EXT_conf_nid generated error", cspsdk::Logging::LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
    return 0;
}
sk_X509_EXTENSION_push(sk, ex);
return 1;
}
```

The problem is that after getting signed, the certificate has the CA value of basic constraints extension set to false. I am at a loss here. Can anybody point out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your issuer can choose to override the constraints like CA: False even though you requested for CA: True. You need to contact them unless you are self-signing your certs.

openssl x509 -in your-signed-cert.pem  -text -noout

Please check if the output contains "CA:True".